# How could I have worded this question better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776811/how-to-click-on-cancel-search-button-programmatically/45781698). I tried to make it as straightforward as it could be, I have even drawn an arrow in Paint.

I want to click a button. That's it.

Some of the comments it received:

- Rob. M (18k reputation): "I see what you mean, do you just want it to not visible?"
- rottenoats (5.5k reputation): "Here, I had created an overly complicated code that allows you to detect when an input is cleared!"

The code in question consists of single `<input type="search">`. "Can you provide us with your html?". Really?

Like, really?

Given that people who answer me have significantly more rep than me, this *implicitly implies* that they are indeed correct, and I am not. I am trying to find the reason for this.

I completely understand nobody is obliged to answer my questions, but what have I done wrong so people post completely unrelated things and imply that's an answer? How can I get better? How can I influence the situation and prevent people from answering with unrelated stuff?

It would be very rude to just reply with "Could you please read question again and make sure you understand what is being asked", but I barely can fight the urge to. Is there anything productive I can do about this?

Comment: I'm truly baffled at the amount of down-votes this question has received. It's an honest attempt at identifying (perceived) mistakes in their question asking ability, and trying to improve themselves for the future. This is the kind of behaviour we want to encourage, not prevent.

Comment: @Rob: Meta really dislikes "How can I improve my question?" questions for some reason.

Comment: I don't think the request of improving questions at main site causes the down votes, but the command like sentence "Please take a look..." (at least I think) and the blaming at the lower part...

Comment: I find "Please take a look" quite polite. I've never once construed it as demanding, and I can't imagine anyone having done the same.

Comment: @ggrr, sorry, I didn't intend it to be a command, or aggressive, or anything like that. It just (politely) prompts the reader to glance at the question to get full context, nothing more. English is not my first language, so some subtle tones might go over my head.

Answer (score 8):

At the time of writing, I only see three answers attached to this question.  The **comments**, however...

Let's address this comment:

> I see what you mean, do you just want it to not visible?

This reads to me more like a clarifying question than anything else.  I don't see any malice or anything negative in this message; if you flagged this as being rude or inappropriate, a moderator would decline it outright since there's nothing that seems offensive.

> Can you provide us with your html?

Part of building a completely verifiable example is to include *complete* code.  Describing it in broader terms is a recipe for misunderstanding.  Who knows; perhaps something else about your HTML and JavaScript, or even your Selenium script could've revealed an underlying problem.

> Here, I had created an overly complicated code that allows you to detect when an input is cleared!

This is the nature of some answerers; they do the long-form answer.  It's not really *their* responsibility to cater to a specific skill level, but you have the ability to tell them that it's not useful to you through comments, downvotes, or both.

---

Nothing here seems to rise to the level of being a problem, IMO.  It's the nature of understanding how the ebb and flow of questions and answers happen.  Your question is well-received and to me seems *alright*, so I don't have any specific advice on how you can improve your question.

My recommendation in general would be to indicate what you're looking for in an answer and keep persistent with it.  I've had that experience with a recent question I asked, and simply keeping persistent and weeding out poor answers was all I could do.

Comment: Provide "too much" code, and people harp on the Minimal aspect of it; provide "too little" code, and people harp on the Complete aspect, despite both cases actually being Minimal *and* Complete examples (not necessarily the same example in the same question). You can see why the asker is in such a dilemma.

Comment: Here's another example of a question where a single self-explanatory CSS selector is all the MCVE that you need, and yet people asked "Can you post the relevant code?" like they were completely blind to that one line of code that's already there, forcing the asker to add a completely irrelevant declaration block (thereby making the example no longer Minimal): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639282/notempty-css-selector-is-not-working

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't disagree that it's tough to find a balance.  I'm only offering it as a general theory as to why that comment was made.  I'm not sure more code in the question is wholly needed.

Comment: I'm also not ruling out users who are on autopilot when it comes to that, either...

Answer (score 1):

> The code in question consists of single `input type="search"`. "Can you provide us with your html?". Really?

The original version of your question does not point out that the cancel button you're talking about is being placed there automatically by the browser. One can figure that out now that you talk about it not being part of the DOM but I think what you put in the comments:

> "cancel button" is not some custom construct, unfortunately, it's part of native `<input type="search">` control as rendered in Chrome

is a lot more straight-forward. You always want to be explicit when talking about browser specific behavior. (You might argue that they should have been able to tell from the image that it was the default button and not a custom one but remember that not everyone can see images and your alt text doesn't point out that it's the native control either. I don't know that those two users had that issue but it's something to keep in mind.)

I ran across [a question that was somewhat similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692762/use-javascript-to-click-on-a-pseudo-element) (but doesn't help with your situation unfortunately) and the only relevant difference is that it's immediately clear that what's being discussed isn't in the DOM.

Otherwise I don't see anything else to change except Makoto's suggestion of including what you expect from an answer.

Comment: Well, original version of question has "I have a `<input type="search">`", which I thought would be enough given this has explicit type indication and `html5` in tags. So, it *had* source from the very beginning.

Comment: However, as I am receiving a steady stream of downvotes now for both questions, I don't think this matters anymore. I have learned my lesson.